# How to write Multiple Element in the XML using JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Sample XML which i have to generate using JAVA
    
        
            sense
            168
            192.168.140.150
            
            002EC0FEFF83EA97

Code Used I have written so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.SimpleTimeZone;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class SampleCode {

    public static final String xmlFilePath = "C:\\Users\\harsh.sharma\\Desktop\\Sense Performance\\Generated\\xmlfile.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {  
                            String cid_Value="168";
                            String ip_Value="192.168.140.150";
                            String id_Value="002EC0FEFF83EA97";
                            String sensorsid_Value="002EC0FEFF8FFF27";
                            String desc_Value=" ";
                            String batt_Value="6.60";
                            String sig_Value="-55";
                            String scount_Value="0";
                            String rdate_Value="15/05/2015 21:47:04";



                            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                            //get current date time with Date() 
                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            String mdate_Value=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

                            DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

                            //root element
                            Element root = document.createElement("msgs");
                            document.appendChild(root);

                            //msg element
                            Element msg = document.createElement("msg");
                            root.appendChild(msg);

                            //type element
                            Element type = document.createElement("type");
                            msg.appendChild(type);
                            type.setTextContent("Sense");

                            //cid element
                            Element cid = document.createElement("cid");
                            msg.appendChild(cid);
                            cid.setTextContent(cid_Value);

                            //ip element
                            Element ip = document.createElement("ip");
                            msg.appendChild(ip);
                            ip.setTextContent(ip_Value);

                            Element errs = document.createElement("errs");
                            msg.appendChild(errs);

                            //id element
                            Element id = document.createElement("id");
                            msg.appendChild(id);
                            id.setTextContent(id_Value);

                            //sensors element
                            Element sensors = document.createElement("sensors");
                            msg.appendChild(sensors);

                            //Sensor element
                            Element sensor = document.createElement("sensor");
                            //sensors.appendChild(sensor);


                           sensor.setAttribute("sensorsid",sensorsid_Value);
                           sensor.setAttribute("desc",desc_Value);           
                           sensor.setAttribute("batt",batt_Value);
                           sensor.setAttribute("sig", sig_Value);
                           sensor.setAttribute("scount",scount_Value);
                           sensor.setAttribute("rdate",rdate_Value);
                           sensor.setAttribute("mdate",mdate_Value);

                           sensors.appendChild(sensor);

                            // create the xml file
                            //transform the DOM Object to an XML File

                            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
                            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));
                            // If you use
                            // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                            // the output will be pushed to the standard output ...
                            // You can use that for debugging
                            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);



                            System.out.println("Done creating XML File");


                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {

                            pce.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {

                            tfe.printStackTrace();

                        }

    }

}
```

I want it should give me multiple rows under the sensor Element, I want to write the loop that I can generate multiple data for the sensor Element